# Consuming a Server-Sent Event Feed with Django Channels

Tags: django, server-sent-events, channel

From the [things I've read](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/3/17/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django), [`django-channels`](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) looks like a good fit for what I want to do: listen to a [stream of events from Particle.IO](https://docs.particle.io/reference/api/#get-a-stream-of-your-events) and record the ones I'm interested in. However, all of the examples I've found seem to be chatroom-based, where the senders and receivers are both part of the `django-channels` set up. How do I create a long-polling task to listen to an *external* API feed and act on new events as they appear in the feed?

Answer (score 0):

Per the author, [this can't be done with `channels`.](https://twitter.com/andrewgodwin/status/714825168258883584)

Comment: Seems like this needs to be updated, haven't tried it yet but looks promising: [django-eventstream](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream)